# Limit based on a column's values (not # of rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to limit the number of phrases resulting from the following query:

```
SELECT phrase_txt, word_txt FROM phrase_word
LEFT JOIN phrase ON phrase.id = phrase_word.phrase_id
LEFT JOIN word ON word.id = phrase_word.word_id;

| PHRASE_TXT | WORD_TXT |
-------------------------
|     Iambad |        i |
|     Iambad |       am |
|     Iambad |      bad |
|        Car |      car |
|     tellme |     tell |
|     tellme |       me |
```

Expected output:

```
| PHRASE_TXT | WORD_TXT |
-------------------------
|     Iambad |        i |
|     Iambad |       am |
|     Iambad |      bad |
|        Car |      car |
```

Adding *LIMIT 0,2* doesn't help, as it limits the number of words, not phrases. Let's say 2:

```
| PHRASE_TXT | WORD_TXT |
-------------------------
|     Iambad |        i |
|     Iambad |       am |
```

More details in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0e6b/2).

Comment: Do you want unique phrases or what?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter by accident. Here goes the full question.

Comment: Duplicate phrases are fine. This query is important cause I need to sample results. Like "100 phrases along with their words".

Comment: Consider providing a proper data set, together with the result set you'd expect from your query - either as an SQLFIDDLE or as a set of CREATE and INSERT statements.

Comment: Since you're using MySql (and it allows in-line variable assignments) you can add a pseudo-column (PhraseNo) that numbers phrases and then use `WHEN PhraseNo < ...`.  I hope your query returns an `record ID` of some kind so it's order can'be preserved.

Comment: How about using `DISTINCT` on the phrases?  (Not really sure what you want from your question.)  It would help if you could provide the SQL you have tried and how it is not working for you.  Show us the result set that you want as well.

Comment: Please check the SQL Fiddle I just added. Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're asking. Please edit the additional details into the question and throw out the SQL fiddle. It's not OK for your question to *depend* on an external link to be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the `LIMIT` in a subquery to limit the number of `phrases` that are returned:

```
SELECT phrase_txt, 
  word_txt 
FROM 
(
  select phrase_txt, id
  from phrase
  order by id
  limit 2
) p
LEFT JOIN phrase_word
  ON p.id = phrase_word.phrase_id
LEFT JOIN word 
  ON word.id = phrase_word.word_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0e6b/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT phrase.text AS p, word.text AS w FROM phrase_word
  JOIN (select * from phrase limit 2) phrase ON phrase.id = phrase_word.phrase_id
  LEFT JOIN word ON word.id = phrase_word.word_id;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/152cc/5).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you used Left Join?
Well this is the simplest i could think of:

```
 SELECT phrase.text AS p, 
        word.text AS w 
   FROM phrase_word
  INNER JOIN phrase 
     ON phrase.id = phrase_word.phrase_id
  INNER JOIN word 
     ON word.id = phrase_word.word_id
  INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT distinct id 
              FROM phrase 
             Limit 2 ) T1
     ON phrase.id = T1.id;
```